# rearranging the digits of 7524693

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In the number 7524693, how many digits will be as far away from the beginning of the number if arranged in ascending order as they are in the number?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions are better received if you explain what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 4):

Why in the world are you asking such a question rather than just **doing** it?
The digits, in increasing order, are 2345679.  Which digits are "as far away from the beginning of the number as they were originally?

Answer (score 0):

7524693

2345679

0000100

So the answer is 1